# How can I start a variable index containing a number? robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I need to start my variable ${i} containing int 1, to utilize the variable in xpath.

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE     1    ${row}
       ${SKU}   Get Text    xpath://*[@id="tblList"]/tbody/tr[${i}]/td[1]
       Input Text      ${Devolucoes.addEtiqueta}   000000${SKU}0000
       Click Element   ${botoes.btnAdicionar}
END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the issue - in your current code, you're giving the lower and upper range bounds already, e.g. `${i}` will go from 1 to row-1?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign int values to variables by putting the int inside the brackets like:

```
${i}    Set Variable    ${1}
```

or

```
${i}    Set Variable    ${10}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You helped me a lot!